# uiviewcontroller still retaining after remove from superview, is it retain cycle issue

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, retain-cycle

i have a UIViewController subclass ABCViewController.On a button long press, I open a UIPopover containing a UIViewController(AddProduct) On abuton long press.The add product contains a cancel button which brings user back to ABCViewControl.and in instruments allocation tool it also disappears.Fine till this point.Some thing like this..

```
-(void)openProductPopUp:(int)productId action:(BOOL)action{

AddProduct *addproduct = [[AddProduct alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddProductNew" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[addproduct setProductId:productId];
[addproduct setIsAddingProduct:action];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                               initWithRootViewController:addproduct];
[addproduct setDelegate:self];***//weak in add product***
[addproduct setDatabasePath:databasePath];
[addproduct setBackTracker:nil];
[addproduct setArrCategories:self.arrCategoryForPopUp];
UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]  initWithContentViewController:nav];

popover.delegate = self;
[popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(576 , 490) animated:NO];
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(512, 430, 1, 1) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
self.popOver=popover;
[addproduct setPopUp:popover];***//weak in add product***
addProduct = YES;
```

}

The AddProduct contains a edit button which opens a seperate uiviewcontroller(AddProductSeparateViewController).It (AddProduct) also contains a cancel button.On cancel button click user comes back to ABCViewCintroller.

**Problem:**AddProduct is releases in this process but AddProductSeparateViewController is not released as per allocation tools live object and dealloc breakpoint.

The code in AddProduct to open AddProductSeparateViewController is as follows:

```
-(IBAction)Edit:(id)sender {

[delegate openEditProductPage:self.productId action:NO];
```

}

This delegate basically inform ABCViewController to open AddProductSeparateViewController.

```
-(void)openEditProductPage:(int)productId action:(BOOL)action{

[self.popOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

[self openAddEditProductSeparatePage:productId action:action];
```

}

```
-(void)openAddEditProductSeparatePage:(int)productId action:(BOOL)action{

[self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];

self.isSalesVuOrderScreenHidden = YES;
[self setControlVisibility:YES];
btnClockIn.hidden=YES;
btnLogout.hidden=YES;
[btnBack.titleLabel setHidden:NO];

self.viewController = [[AddProductSeparateViewController alloc] init];
[self.viewController setProductId:productId];
[self.viewController setSalesVuScreen:self];
[self.viewController setIsAddingProduct:action];
[self.viewController setDelegate:self];
[self.viewController setDatabasePath:databasePath];
[self.viewController setBackTracker:nil];
[self.viewController setArrCategories:self.arrCategoryForPopUp];
[self.viewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,48,1024,self.view.frame.size.height-48)];
[self.view addSubview:self.viewController.view];
```

}

The code in AddProductSeparateViewController to cancel is as follows:

```
-(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {


[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

}

why is AddProductSeparateViewController is not released in this process.

Thanks

Comment: Create a property of UIPopOverController,don't initialize it locally

Comment: How do you declare `self.viewController` in `ABCViewController`? As a `strong` property? Just remove `self.view` from its superview will not mean its deallocated, you'll also need to `nil` out `self.viewController` in `ABCViewController`.

Comment: @Rich yes it sense, i have taken it as strong,(weak crashed and logically not correct also).And for that i have to inform(delegate/notify) ABCViewController to make self.viewController as nil right on event -(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {


[self.view removeFromSuperview];
}

Comment: @Rich add it as answer so that i can accept i will make it nil by delegate communication. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare `self.viewController` in `ABCViewController` as a `strong` property you need to make sure that you `nil` that reference out when removing its view.

Just removing `self.view` from its superview will not mean its deallocated. You should do this by a call back (add a delegate) to `ABCViewController` when `cancel:` happens.